# Pandas custom groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there any way to use a custom groupby function in Pandas? for example suppose I have the data below.

```
a|b|c
-----
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 7
1 4 3
1 4 5
2 1 0
2 3 5
2 4 6
2 3 6
3 1 0
4 1 0
4 2 3
```

Is it possible to group my data by a and b if a is not in  [2,4] and by a otherwise?

In the example above I'd like to get the following groups:

```
123
124

137

143
145

210
235
246
236

310

410
423
```

The column b is an open set so I would ideally like a function that is independent of the values in b

Answer (score 2):

you can `mask` the column b when a meets your condition with `isin` and replace by any value (like 1), then use this in the `groupby`.

```
for _, dfg in df.groupby(['a', 
                          df['b'].mask(df['a'].isin([2,4]), # condition
                                       1)]):  # replacement value
    print('new group')
    print(dfg)
new group
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  4
new group
   a  b  c
2  1  3  7
new group
   a  b  c
3  1  4  3
4  1  4  5
new group
   a  b  c
5  2  1  0
6  2  3  5
7  2  4  6
8  2  3  6
new group
   a  b  c
9  3  1  0
new group
    a  b  c
10  4  1  0
11  4  2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can also try:

Here, if the value of a is in `[2,4]` it'll ignore the value in column `b` and will group them together.

```
for _, k in df.groupby([df.a.values, np.where(df.a.isin([2, 4]), 0, df.b)]):
    print(k)
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  4
   a  b  c
2  1  3  7
   a  b  c
3  1  4  3
4  1  4  5
   a  b  c
5  2  1  0
6  2  3  5
7  2  4  6
8  2  3  6
   a  b  c
9  3  1  0
    a  b  c
10  4  1  0
11  4  2  3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this indirectly. First define a function that defines groups:

```
def grouping(row):
    if row.a in [2,4]:
        return 0
    else:
        return f"{row.a}_{row.b}"
```

Then use `apply` to get grouping column:

```
df['grouping'] = df.apply(grouping)
```

Then group by `grouping` column:

```
df = df.groupby('grouping')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a temporary Series of tuples, containing either `(a)` or `(a, b)` and then group by that:

```py
a = df[['a']].apply(tuple, axis=1)
ab = df[['a', 'b']].apply(tuple, axis=1)

df['group'] = np.where(df['a'].isin([2,4]), a, ab)
```

Output

```
> df.sort_values('group')

 a  b  c  group
 1  2  3 (1, 2)
 1  2  4 (1, 2)
 1  3  7 (1, 3)
 1  4  3 (1, 4)
 1  4  5 (1, 4)
 2  1  0   (2,)
 2  3  5   (2,)
 2  4  6   (2,)
 2  3  6   (2,)
 3  1  0 (3, 1)
 4  1  0   (4,)
 4  2  3   (4,)
```